# How to set lateinit Kotlin property to null

Tags: kotlin, conductor, kotlin-null-safety

The below class has a very unique lifecycle, which requires me to temporarily null out `lateinit` properties

```
class SalesController : BaseController, SalesView {
    @Inject lateinit var viewBinder: SalesController.ViewBinder
    @Inject lateinit var renderer: SalesRenderer
    @Inject lateinit var presenter: SalesPresenter
    lateinit private var component: SalesScreenComponent

    override var state = SalesScreen.State.INITIAL  //only property that I want to survive config changes

    fun onCreateView(): View {  /** lateinit variables are set here */ }
    fun onDestroyView() {
         //lateinit variables need to be dereferences here, or we have a memory leak 
         renderer = null!! //here's the problem: throws exception bc it's a non-nullable property
```

}
    }

Here's how it's used by the framework.

```
controller.onCreateView() //same instance of controller
controller.onDestroyView() //same instance of controller
controller.onCreateView() //same instance of controller
controller.onDestroyView() //same instance of controller
```

My `lateinit` properties are injected by dagger, and I need to set them to `null` in `onDestroyView` - or have a memory leak. This however is not possible in kotlin, as far as I am aware (without reflection). I could make these properties nullable, but that would defeat the purpose of Kotlin's null safety.

I'm not quite sure how to solve this. Ideally there could be some type of annotation processor that would generate java code to null out specific variables automatically in `onDestroyView`?

Comment: why you have a leak? maybe the problem is on the SalesController rather than on its properties? I've never needed to explicitly set to null a property injected by Dagger to avoid leak problems...

Comment: @Massimo Conductor's controller instances survive config changes https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor

Comment: If you need to nullify them, you don't need to have `lateinit` then. And I'm pretty sure you are don't have any leak there, you are just mixing some definitions. You would leak if your presenter would reference your View, not vice-versa

Answer (score 11):

Kotlin `lateinit` properties use `null` as an uninitialized flag value, and there's no clean way to set `null` in the backing field of a `lateinit` property without reflection.

---

However, Kotlin allows you to override the properties behavior using delegated properties. Seems like there's no delegate that allows that in `kotlin-stdlib`, but if you need exactly this behavior, you can [implement your own delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#delegated-properties) to do that, adding some code to your utils:

```
class ResettableManager {
    private val delegates = mutableListOf<ResettableNotNullDelegate<*, *>>()

    fun register(delegate: ResettableNotNullDelegate<*, *>) { delegates.add(delegate) }

    fun reset() { delegatesToReset.forEach { it.reset() } }
}

class Resettable<R, T : Any>(manager: ResettableManager) {
    init { manager.register(this) }

    private var value: T? = null

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T =
            value ?: throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException()

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>, t: T) { value = t }

    fun reset() { value = null }
}
```

And the usage:

```
class SalesController : BaseController, SalesView {
    val resettableManager = ResettableManager()
    @set:Inject var viewBinder: SalesController.ViewBinder by Resettable(resettableManager)
    @set:Inject var renderer: SalesRenderer by Resettable(resettableManager)
    @set:Inject var presenter: SalesPresenter by Resettable(resettableManager)

    fun onDestroyView() {
        resettableManager.reset()
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think you could have `@Inject` on a 'member property with delegate'.

Comment: @mfulton26, thanks for the remark! Do you think it will work with `@set:Inject`?

Comment: Good thinking. I think it will (I'm not using Dagger or anything but at least that compiles).

Comment: This is perfect. Works great - except I'm not sure what to do now with named injections. normally I did `@field:[Inject Named("bold")]`, but you can't use `@field` with delegated properties

Comment: @hotkey nope. Dagger2 ignores the `@Named` part